# Converting C array to Python bytes

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to use Cython to run a C++ library in python3 environment.
When I try to return the int array back to python like this:

```
def readBytes(self, length):
    cdef int *buffer = []
    self.stream.read(buffer, length)
    return buffer
```

I get the error

```
    return buffer
                ^
Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object
```

P.S. I don't get errors if I use

```
 cdef char *buffer = ''
```

Comment: it looks like stream.read() allocates the memory pointed by `buffer`. If this is the case, you cannot return to python space data allocated in C++ space.

Comment: @flebool how come it works on char?

Comment: See answer, too short to stay here

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `stream.read()` allocates the memory pointed by `buffer`. If this is the case, you cannot return to python space data allocated in C++ space. You should:

1) create a python object, or a `numpy` array if you prefer, in python/cython code

2) copy the data from the allocated memory pointed by `*buffer` to your new shiny python object allocated in python space. You can then return this object.

This is necessary because python cannot deal with the memory allocated in `C` space in any way, and the memory allocated by your `C` code is leaking, i.e. it will not be deallocated.

Now you also asked why you do not get the error with `cdef char *buffer = ''`. In this latter case, cython recognizes that `buffer` points to a string, and automatically generates a new python object with the content pointed by `buffer`. Example follows for `ipython`:

```
%%cython
def ReturnThisString():
    cdef char *buffer = 'foobar'
    return buffer

print ReturnThisString() #this outputs 'foobar'
```

Notice that `buffer` is initialized by your `C` compiler on the stack, and there's no guarantee that when you use this function from python the string will still be there at that memory position. However, when cython runs the return statement it automatically initializes a python string from your `char *` pointer. (In python 3 I guess it is converted to `bytes` as @Veedrac says, but this is a minor point). In this second case, the creation of the python object and the copy operation is hidden and taken care by `cython`, but it is still there.

Answer (score 0):

`char` can be automatically coerced to `bytes` because Cython thinks that they're approximately the same and can do it fast. Note that `char *` pointers will be null terminated by default.

This is not implemented for `int *`. You will typically want to [coerce to a Numpy object](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy) (this is actually wrapping the array). If you want something faster, think about `cpython.array`.

Comment: Not sure how to apply this (coerce to a Numpy object) to my code, I've tried it and it gives me an error: Pointer base type does not match cython.array base type

Comment: Notice that simply coercing the array will leak the pointed memory. This is a good idea only if you plan to use locally (in cython) the data, and return something different from the data itself.